# Digit recognition reading image problem. It says my image is in wrong shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have drawn digit in paint software and saved it as png. Then i uploaded the image in the same folder with this ipynb. The thing is, it says that the shape is incorrect. The error was detected at the end of the code.

```py
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

x_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1)
x_test = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_test, axis=1)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3)

accuracy, loss = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)

print(accuracy)
print(loss)
model.save('digits.model')

for x in range(1,6):
    img = cv.imread(f'{x}.png')[:,:,0]
    img = np.invert(np.array([img]))
    prediction = model.predict(img)
    print(f'the result is probably:{np.argmax(prediction)}')
    plt.imshow(img[0], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    plt.show
```

Error image can be seen below. I don't get it, which line(s) I should fix in order to read the digit image properly?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your model input shape is `(28, 28)`. For a prediction by your model you should pass your input in the same size that you created the model.

So, try to resize image before feeding it to your model for prediction.

```
img = cv.resize(img, (28,28))
```

Comment: where i should add this line of code? can you enlighten me

Comment: @JettBlack After reading your image by ``cv.imread()`` in ``for`` loop.